# SQLAlchemy querying function

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I've got a function, which takes a single argument, runs a query and in the end returns some values after certain calculations.

My query is something similar to this:

```
def my_function(passed_argument):
    query = Session.query(t).filter(t.column_c == passed_argument).all()
    # ... do some work with query
    return some_value
```

What I would like to achieve however is to:
Pass the function a list (instead of a single argument) which contains multiple values and for t.column_c to match any of those.

Ex. **`Select * from t where column_c = my_list[0] or column_c = my_list[1] or column_c = my_list[2] ..`** and so on.

What's the way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend something like this:

```
def my_function(*passed_arguments):
    query = Session.query(t).filter(t.column_c.in_(passed_arguments)).all()
    # ... do some work with query
    return some_value
```

You can call the method like this:

```
my_function(123, 456, 789)
```

Comment: Hello WoLpH. This is remarkable. Thank you very much! I will go ahead and try it right now. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You could put that filtering into the query using the SQL keyword `IN`:

```
SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE col1 IN (2,3,5,7)
SELECT col2 FROM table WHERE col2 IN ('text1','text2')
```